# boost shared_ptr copy issue

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

my question is how do I assign the smart pointer to the other ? I am not sure how to get around the temporary variable either ?

```
typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket            TBoostSocket;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<TBoostSocket>        TSocket;

TSocket createSocket(const IpcNode::TPath& a_path) {

    TSocket socket(new TBoostSocket(*this->getIoservice()));
    return socket;

}
```

//in another function

```
TSocket result();

result= createSocket(a_path);
```

// compiler output
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

41: error: assignment of function ‘IPC::TcpServices::TSocket IPC::result()
cannot convert ‘TSocket* {aka    boost::shared_ptr >*}’ to ‘TSocket() {aka boost::shared_ptr >()}’ in assignment

I know I am missing something obvious I just can see it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following declares a function (that takes no arguments and returns `TSocket`):

```
TSocket result();
```

Change it to:

```
TSocket result;
```

Comment: Thanks I could not see the wood for the trees

Comment: It's a very common gotcha that's extremely easy to overlook (especially with the sort of error messages one tends to get).